# Can I use a different product image for the same product in Schema.org?

Tags: image, schema.org

If I have categories.html page with links to product.html page,

is it ok to mark the product-small-image in categories.html as Schema.org `image` of the product, even that there is a better-detailed-image of the product in product.html page?

(I’m using Microdata.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that should be fine.

Note that you could still provide the big image without showing it. This is possible with the `link` element, e.g.:

```html
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <img src="small-image.png" alt="…" />
  <link itemprop="image" href="big-image.png" />
</article>
```

If you want to be really expressive, you could provide an [`ImageObject`](http://schema.org/ImageObject) value and use its [`thumbnail`](http://schema.org/thumbnail) property:

```html
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <div itemprop="image" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
    <img itemprop="thumbnail" src="small-image.png" alt="…" />
    <link itemprop="contentUrl" href="big-image.png" />
  </div>
</article>
```